# arch/x86/Makefile:184: *** Compiler lacks asm-goto support.. Stop

Tags: linux, centos, kernel

compiling latest kernel, from kernel.org: (2018.07.23) https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/linux-4.17.9.tar.xz

[under a freshly installed and updated CentOS7 (2018.07.23) like this tutorial used to work fine](https://dwaves.de/2017/06/30/centos-redhat-compiling-the-latest-kernel/)

```
make clean
arch/x86/Makefile:184: *** Compiler lacks asm-goto support..  Stop.
```

while: kernel linux-4.14.57 https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/linux-4.14.57.tar.xz

does not give such error.

this compiler is used:

```
gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada,go,lto --enable-plugin --enable-initfini-array --disable-libgcj --with-isl=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.8.5-20150702/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/isl-install --with-cloog=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.8.5-20150702/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/cloog-install --enable-gnu-indirect-function --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=x86-64 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28) (GCC)
```

Why do I have thos errors ?

Comment: Don't confuse us with your highfalutin lion-king quotes. You will just confuse us.